# EditorFor is not getting the right Editor in ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I have a situation where I want to use a custom `EditorTemplate` with a ViewModel. So I have my ViewModel...

```
class Aspect {
}
class AspectViewModel {
}
```

then my EditorTemplate

- Views

  - Shared

    - EditorTemplates

      - Aspect.cshtml

### Aspect.cshtml

@model AspectViewModel

// other html

Then in another view that takes `AspectViewModel`, I call `@Html.EditorFor(model => model)`, but it does not work. It only works if I use a hard-coded string `@Html.EditorForModel("Aspect")`.

Any idea why it isn't being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should name the editor template `AspectViewModel.cshtml` if it is strongly typed to `AspectViewModel`. Then all you have to do is:

```
@model AspectViewModel
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

or

```
@model SomeViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Aspect)
```

where the `Aspect` property of `SomeViewModel` is of type `AspectViewModel`.

The convention is that the editor/display should be named as the type of the property you are calling it on and not the name of this property.

They also work greatly with collections. For example if you have the following property:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectViewModel> Aspects { get; set; }
}
```

and you use:

```
@model SomeViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Aspects)
```

then the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AspectViewModel.cshtml` editor template wil be rendered for each element of this collection. Thanks to this you really no longer need to ever write `for`/`foreach` loops in your views.

Comment: I really figured it inferred it from the type. Thanks, that works fine. I thought I had tried that already but I guess I must have spelled it wrong.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing as Ciel. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your model is `AspectViewModel`, but your view name is `Aspect`. They must match exactly.